# Calling JS from an applet works in Firefox & Chrome but not Safari

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, safari, applet

I have the following code in an applet to call some Javascript (it's a bit convoluted because the fn that's called gets an object from the DOM identified by divId and calls a function on it).

```
@Override
public final void start() {
  System.err.println("start() method called");
  this.javascript = JSObject.getWindow(this);
  this.jsObjectDivId = getParameter("parent_div_id");
  this.initCallbackFnName = getParameter("init_callback");
  Object args[] = {this.jsObjectDivId, this.initCallbackFnName};
  System.out.print("Calling init_callback\n");
  this.javascript.call("callJS", args);
}
```

The `callJS` function is:

```
window.callJS = function(divId, functionName, jsonArgString) {
  var args, obj;
  obj = $(divId).data('neatObject');
  args = eval(jsonArgString);
  return obj[functionName](args);
};
```

In Firefox/Chrome the `divId` and `functionName` arguments contain valid strings and everything works fine; the desired function is called on the object hanging off the specified DIV data.

In Safari, the `divId` and `functionName` arguments are both reported as a `JavaRuntimeObject` with values of `true`.

```
> divId
  JavaRuntimeObject
    true
```

What gives?

Comment: I have also experienced that safari doesn't support javascript as perfectly as other browsers do

Comment: It seems it's broken in both directions. Calling an applet method from JS returns a useless JavaRuntimeObject too, instead of what I actually want to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LiveConnect is not fully supported in all browsers. Especially, Safari doesn't convert Java Strings to the prober JS equivalent when using `call`. In your case you can just use `eval` at the Applet side instead of `call` and put in a JSON string object with the arguments. Something like:

`javascript.eval(callback + "({\"id\":\"" + id + "\",\"` ... `})")`

Basically, you need to know the cross-browser compatible subset of LiveConnect that works. 
I've written a blog post that describes the subset: http://blog.aarhusworks.com/applets-missing-information-about-liveconnect-and-deployment/

It comes with a LiveConnect test suite which runs in the browser: http://www.jdams.org/live-connect-test

Comment: It's strange. In the latest version of Safari (5.0.5 on OS X 10.6.7) it seems to pass the first arg ok if it can be converted to a string! I've also had some luck with the return values - they work if you use them in a string context but you can't pass them as args to other JS functions unless you concat an empty string to them. E.g., json_parse(applet.getSomeJSON() + "") will work but json_parse(applet.getSomeJSON()) will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with calling a method on an applet in Safari. It was returning a JavaRuntimeObject that I caused an exception when it was user later on.

As pointed out by @edoloughlin I had to use (applet.getMethod() + "") after which point the proper string was evaluated.

The comment saved me a bunch of time so I thought it useful to add here as I can't comment above.