# invoking an applet function through javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2, applet

I need to call an applet method through javascript

my applet method goes like this

```
public class MD5encryption extends Applet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static String doTheEncryption(final String strText) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {

    String strResult = null;
    /* do the encryption*/
    return strResult;
  }
}
```

and my jsp file goes like this

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<script src= "http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    <!-- applet id can be used to get a reference to the applet object -->
    var attributes = { id:'md5appletId', code:'com.package.encryptionMD5.MD5encryption',  width:1, height:1} ;
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'parameters.jnlp'} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
<div>
    <div>
        <s:form action="Login" validate="true">
            <s:textfield name="userName" label="User ID" maxlength="10"
                required="true" onkeypress="return onlyNumbersChars(event)"
                onchange="showDob(this,true)" />
            <s:password name="password" label="Password" required="true"
                maxlength="14" />
            <tr><td><div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="encrypt()"/> <a href="LoginLink.html">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div></td></tr>
        </s:form>
    </div>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
    function encrypt(){
        var password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];

        var md5OfPass = md5appletId.doTheEncryption(password.value);
        password.value = md5OfPass;        

    }
</script>
```

I'm also using the jnlp file which is at the same location as of applet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <applet-desc name="Applet Takes Params" main-class="MD5encryption"
     width="800" height="50">
         <param name="paramStr" value="parameter String"/>
         <param name="paramInt" value="22"/>
    </applet-desc>     
</jnlp>
```

Am i missing something here as I'm not able to access the function of the applet

Comment: Are you getting a javascript error in the console? You can also try opening up the java console to see if there are any exceptions while running the applet

Comment: its throwing javascript error stating that md5appletId.doTheEncryption is not a recognized function

Comment: and `typeof md5appletId` gives you `Object`?

Comment: @shyam  no its giving me  " typeof(md5appletId) = function  " . Even after editing the script like --> var attributes = { id:'md5appletId', archive:'/myProject/WEB-INF/lib/md5Applet.jar' , code:'com.package.encryptionMD5.MD5encryption',  width:1, height:1} ;    .......... I'm not getting the desired result

Comment: @shyam although when I do ::: alert(' md5appletId = ' + md5appletId  + '\n typeof(md5appletId) = ' + typeof(md5appletId));  :::                                                                   it gives me a result as  ::::                                  md5appletId = [object HTMLAppletElement]
 typeof(md5appletId) = function  :::

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a Javascript object to a Java applet in Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247019/how-to-pass-a-javascript-object-to-a-java-applet-in-safari)